# Java Video Tutorials

Tags: java

I was wondering if anyone knows of any good sites for learning java preferably with video lessons.

Comment: Found this anymore like it? http://www.javavideotutes.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse as your IDE, you can check out these tutorials:
http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/

Still useful if you don't use Eclipse, but may be a tad tricky to navigate if you're brand new to Java/programming. :)

Comment: Thank you! I am new to programming however I have been doing java in class for the last few month and find the content we are given hard to learn by. I would ^ you but Im stil a noob

Answer (score 2):

thenewboston.com has some good java tutorials.  They're easy to follow and funny at times. other than that, just read the boring stuff and practice practice by doing projects that interest you.